# jquery animate from object center

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a product viewer similar to the one at the bottom of this page http://www.logitech.com/en-gb/. As you can see the product animates from the center rather than top left which I think is Jquery's default. So what I am doing is trying animate the width and height and then also the offset to make it look like it animates from the center.

My code looks like this:

```
<style>
  body {
    background: black;
  }
  .box {
    background: #fff url('pic.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px 4%;
    float: left;
  }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".box").hover(function() {
            $(".box").not(this).fadeTo(500, 0.5);
            $(this).animate({
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                left: -100,
                top: -100
            }, 500);
        },
        function() {
            $(this).animate({
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                left: 100,
                top: 100
            }, 500);
            $(".box").fadeTo(500, 1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I cannot seem to get this working as I want. Can anyone help with this or suggest a better technique? Many thanks

Comment: I get this from your URL:
Authorization Required
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After playing around I have managed to get the effect I want. Here is the code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        background: black;
      }
      .box {
        background: #fff;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 10px 4%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
      }

      img {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 0;
      }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".box").hover(function() {
                $(".box").not(this).fadeTo(500, 0.1);
                $(this).find('img').animate({
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    left: -50,
                    top: -50
                }, 100);
            },
            function() {
                $(".box").fadeTo(100, 1);
                $(this).find('img').animate({
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0
                }, 500);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, position 'absolute' and the negativ 'left' and 'top' values did the trick for me.

Comment: use jQuery UI with the show method passing in "scale" as a parameter. Thanks Jamie Dixon http://bit.ly/RvMDHR