# Jquery, animating an element from it's center

Tags: jquery, animation, center

I have some elements on a page that I am animating via jquery.

I'm having some minor trouble in figuring out how to have the circles animate from the center of the circle's (not the top left corner that Jquery animates, defaultly)

Consider the following:

```
           var percentage = $("#percent");
           var percentage2 = $("#percent2");
           var percentage3 = $("#percent3");

           var nCircleA = 0;
           var nCircleB = 0;
           var nCircleC = 0;




 function myClick() { /*answer1*/
   $('ul#quiz li').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') === false) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().addClass('deactive');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeClass('deactive');
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') && $(this).is('.viewa')) {
            circle1animate();
            circle2deactive();
            circle3deactive();
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') && $(this).is('.viewb')) {
            circle2animate();
            circle1deactive();
            circle3deactive();
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') && $(this).is('.viewc')) {
            circle3animate();
            circle1deactive();
            circle2deactive();
        }
       }
       });
      }

   function circle1animate() {
    percentage.html(++nCircleA);
    $('.circle1 img').animate({
      width: "+=30.0%",
      height: "+=30.0%"
    }, 600, 'easeOutBounce');
  }

   function circle2animate() {
    percentage2.html(++nCircleB);
    $('.circle2 img').animate({
      width: "+=30.0%",
      height: "+=30.0%"
    }, 600, 'easeOutBounce');
   }

   function circle3animate() {
    percentage3.html(++nCircleC);
    $('.circle3 img').animate({
      width: "+=30.0%",
      height: "+=30.0%"
   }, 600, 'easeOutBounce');
  }
  //deactive

   function circle1deactive() {
     percentage.html(nCircleA - 1 < 0 ? 0 : --nCircleA);
    $('.circle1 img').animate({
      width: "80px",
      height: "80px"
    }, 600, 'easeOutBounce').removeClass('trans');
  }

  function circle2deactive() {
   percentage2.html(nCircleB - 1 < 0 ? 0 : --nCircleB);
   $('.circle2 img').animate({
    width: "80px",
    height: "80px"
   }, 600, 'easeOutBounce').removeClass('trans');
 }

  function circle3deactive() {
    percentage3.html(nCircleC - 1 < 0 ? 0 : --nCircleC);
    $('.circle3 img').animate({
    width: "80px",
    height: "80px"
   }, 600, 'easeOutBounce').removeClass('trans');
 }



 myClick();
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/4f8qw/2/)

Comment: I dont know of any quick solution to this, but I would either: position the circles vertically and horizontally centered in a wrapper with more height&width and then make them bigger inside the wrapper (still being centered). OR you can place them via js-calculation according to the animation state with dynamic offsets.

Comment: How are the elements you want to animate positioned?

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964419/jquery-animate-from-object-center

Comment: Yup, that was it.. setting negative positioning on the animation function solved it, thank you